# Defining grid for Mapcache for data stored in SRID 3912?

Tags: mapserver, srid, mapcache

How do I define the grid for Mapcache when the data is stored in SRID 3912?

```
<grid name="SLOGRID">
<size>256 256</size>
<extent>413919,90129,694326,133000</extent> -- those are wrong
<srs>EPSG:3912</srs>
<units>m</units>
<resolutions>2000 1000 500 400 200 100 50 25 20 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2.5 2 1.5 1 0.3</resolutions> -- those are wrong
</grid>
```

Basically I have problems determining the resoulutions and extent.

Comment: If I take the [EPSG](http://www.epsg-registry.org) extents for 3912 and check all 4 corners (13.38,45.42 16.61,46.88 - plus the other 2 corners), the min-max values are: 373233,31868 625985,194134.

Comment: Thanks, mkennedy will use those and report back about results :)